# PPP Connection: Software Center 'Install' button is not active

Tags: networking, software-center, usb-modem, button

I'm using PPP connection with Huawei Mobile Partner dial up software on Ubuntu 14.04. Problem is when I want to download software via Ubuntu Software Center.

The <kbd>Install</kbd> button is not active just like when there is no connection with internet. When I connect my USB modem with Network Manager Applet everything is good. But I need to use dial up software from Huawei. I know I can install via terminal but I don't want to be forced to type commands if I have nice GUI installation method.

Menu in Software Center '**File->Install**' is also not active. If I run Software Center from sudo '**File->Install**' is active but the <kbd>Install</kbd> button is not. Odd. I already tried re-installing Software Center.

How can I fix it without launching Software Center with `sudo` or `gksu`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this.

If you have problems with the <kbd>Install</kbd> button in Ubuntu Software Center try my solution:

Open terminal and type or paste this line

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/netstatus.py
```

Scroll down to the end of the file and search for this

```
# simply query
def get_network_state():
    """ get the NetState state """
    global NETWORK_STATE
    return NETWORK_STATE
```

Next change `return NETWORK_STATE` to `return 70`
so it must look like this

```
# simply query
def get_network_state():
    """ get the NetState state """
    global NETWORK_STATE
    return 70
```

Save file, close Ubuntu Software Center and launch it again. From now Install button should be always accessible for you even if you don't have connection with internet.
Simple workaround. Hope it help someone.